# NDSolve fixed step problem

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

**Working example here**: [Drive folder](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2482t7JZUrnfk1FUG9fSVFOQWdTdkh6ellJS0NUeFJuc0NpeGNjdDctT3BPYnhSMk9Ja28&usp=sharing) (have both files in the same directory! **Notice**: the line `<<variables'` in the file seems to throw an error for me, but actually the whole code works so don't worry about the error if you get it.)

I need to solve a system of DEs that are apparently differential-algebraic equations. When I run:

```
NDSolve[Join[quadPayDynamics, initialConditions], 
   varsToSolveFor, {t, 0, finalSimTime},
   StartingStepSize -> 1/10,
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}
   ];
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option
Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}.
```

*Fine*, I use that method (which I have no idea about) and for a simple version of `quadPayDynamics` I get the solution. However, for more complicated cases if I want to run the simulation for 1 second, `NDsolve` takes time steps on the order of 0.0001 seconds. I ask myself, is there a problem in `quadPayDynamics`? To test, I try to simulate with `finalSimTime`=0.001 seconds to plot the result and see if weird oscillations come up. *Now NDSolve is taking time steps on the order of 1*10^-7 seconds*!!!

So I try to use:

```
NDSolve[Join[quadPayDynamics, initialConditions], 
   varsToSolveFor, {t, 0, finalSimTime},
   StartingStepSize -> 1/10,
   Method -> {"FixedStep", "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"},
   ];
```

**Now I get the error**:

```
The method NDSolve`FixedStep is not currently implemented to solve
differential-algebraic equations. Use Method -> Automatic instead.
```

But Method Automatic doesn't work!! To be honest, I'm pressing buttons here and am not really sure what I'm doing. All I know is that I want a coarse, not extremely precise solution quickly to a complicated problem that current with `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` will take >10 hours to solve. How can I get a fast solution? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Becausw those are lists I didn't include -they are 1000s of lines. How could I include them?

Comment: Include a *minimal* example of those lists that represents your problem then. People will have a hard time troubleshooting your problem otherwise.

Comment: @MarcoB I added the working example at the top of my original post (download the Mathematica file and saved variables from the Google Drive folder). Thanks in advance for your help. Notice how my problem currently seems more to be a convergence issue of some sort...

Comment: @MichaelE2 I added a working example at the top of my original post :)

Comment: Voting to close because the code link is dead, no one was able to solve this problem, and probably the OP has moved on.